# How to format links in the hyperef package to be descriptive?

Tags: hyperref

Using the `\hyperref` package, how is it possible to get a descriptive link, rather than just a link.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

    \href{RAF-independent MAPK1/3 activation}{http://www.reactome.org/content/detail/R-HSA-112409}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

While I want the link to look like [RAF-independent MAPK1/3 activation](http://www.reactome.org/content/detail/R-HSA-112409)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is `\href{URL}{text}`, not `\href{text}{URL}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

    \href{http://www.reactome.org/content/detail/R-HSA-112409}{RAF-independent MAPK1/3 activation}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]